# How to setAudioSessionId, setAudioAttributes, and setScreenOnWhilePlaying in VideoView

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, android-audiomanager

Sorry, not sure if noob question. As the title says, I want to use `setAudioSessionId`, `setAudioAttributes`, and `setScreenOnWhilePlaying` in a `VideoView`. But I can't seem to find anything that teaches how to do it. There's no `getMediaPlayer` method in VideoView and setting them in `onPrepared` where the MediaPlayer instance is getting passed to seems to be too late. So how can I use them in VideoView, is there some other VideoView initialization callback that I can use? Or is there anything that would allow me to set the stream type for the app in general? And maintain screen on without using wakelock like `setScreenOnWhilePlaying`?

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: hi, anyone? help please?

Comment: anyone? help? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VideoView is a wrapper of MediaPlayer. VideoView instantiate a MediaPlayer object inside of it and never exposes it.

- Regarding setAudioAttributes(), VideoView provides the same API and you can use it.
- MediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true) is called within VideoView. So you don't need to worry about calling setScreenOnWhilePlaying on your side.
- For setAudioSessionId(), VideoView doesn't provide a corresponding API to it, but it has getAudioSessionId(). Won't it satisfy your needs?